# How to convert Array[String] to Array[Any] in Spark/Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, graph, graphframes

I am trying to generate sourceIds for the parallelPersonalizedPageRank algorithm inside Graphframes and call the algoirthm as following:

```
val PPRIdCS = studentCS.select("id").collect.map(row => row.getString(0))
val ranksCS = studentGraph
  .parallelPersonalizedPageRank
  .resetProbability(0.15)
  .maxIter(10)
  .sourceIds(PPRIdCS)
  .run()
```

The error information I got is as following:

```
Message: <console>:46: error: type mismatch;
found   : Array[String]
required: Array[Any]
Note: String <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 
3.2.10).sourceIds(PPRIdCS)
```

I could not figure out what is the way to cast a String type to Any type, or a way to map String to Any while generating PPRIdCS. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried .asInstanceOf[Any]?

Comment: I tried this val PPRIdCS = studentCS.select("id").collect.map(row => row.getString(0)).map(_.asInstanceOf(Any)). But get the error saying: Name: Unknown Error
Message: <console>:47: error: T0 does not take parameters
       val PPRIdCS = studentCS.select("id").collect.map(row => row.getString(0)).map(\_.asInstanceOf(Any))

Comment: `val arr = Array("a", "b")
  val asAny: Array[Any] = arr.map(_.asInstanceOf[Any])`

Comment: Thank you Jordan. I made an error of using () for Any type. What you suggested works. The one in the answer seem to be a more direct way to define the type as well.

Comment: np. made it as an answer

Comment: @GuanghuaShu If one of the proposed solutions worked, then please take a few seconds to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted from my comment, you can map to .asInstanceOf[Any].

Example:

```
val arr = Array("a", "b") 
val asAny = arr.map(_.asInstanceOf[Any])
```

This also appears to work...

```
val asAny = arr.asInstanceOf[Array[Any]]
```

Now doing this is assuming you for some reason do not want to specify the type explicitly as noted by the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just be explicit about the types:

```
val PPRIdCS: Array[Any] = studentCS.select("id").collect.map(row => row.getString(0))
```

or better

```
val PPRIdCS: Array[Any] = studentCS.select("id").collect.map(row => row(0))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster if you swapped `map` and `collect`? The `map` looks as if it could throw away quite a few unnecessary row entries, then there would be no need to send them to master node.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I think swap map and collect is a good idea. In this particular case it may not matter since "id" has only one element.